# Couldn't send a value from client to server in Angular 2+ to Node

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am trying to send an email value from client to server side, but I am getting some errors. My code below.

HTML

```
<form class="example-form" (ngSubmit)="uptpwd()">  
        <input class="form-control lht" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email"> 
        <br/> 
        <br/> 
        <button class="lgbtn" type="submit">Enter</button> 
        </form>
```

TS

```
export class ForgotComponent implements OnInit {

 email: string = ''; 

   constructor(private auth: AuthService,
          private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
          private http: Http,
          public toast: ToastComponent) { }

         ngOnInit() {

           }
       uptpwd(email)
         {
      this.auth.uptpwd(this.email).subscribe();
     }
      }
```

Service

```
uptpwd(email){
 return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/sendmail`,email).map(res => 
 res.json());
  }
```

Server

```
    app.post('/sendmail', function (req, res) {

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'f*******@gmail.com',
        pass: *************
    }
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: *******@gmail.com
    to:req.body.email,
    subject: 'Password Reset',
    text: 'Click the link to reset password: ',
};

app.options('/sendmail', function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});



res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost:4200/forgot'); // Change this to your Angular 2 port number
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => 

{
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message %s sent: %s', 

info.messageId, info.response);
    });

})
```

> Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   forgot:1 Failed to load http://localhost:3000/sendmail: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Answer (score 0):

try to make it this way, I had faced the same error I made it work in the following way,

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```